# Unit of measurement from standard error prediction map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, statistics, kriging, units

I am performing an ordinary kriging analysis and came out with the prediction standard error map. I would like to know the units of such map. Can anyone help?

Comment: SE should be in the same unit as your prediction

Answer (score 4):

Standard error (SE) and standard deviation (SD) are statistics which have the same unit of the underlying variable, while the variance unit is the square of it.

For example, suppose the variable being interpolated is elevation in meters (m). The SE and SD statistics will be given in meters (m), whereas variance in square meters (m²).

Based on the terminology used in the question, I assume you are working with the Geostatistical Analyst tool from ArcGIS. In their [resources.arcgis.com](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00310000003v000000) page, the explanation provided is only operational (how to do).

> Ordinary kriging provides a standard error map that shows the uncertainty related to the predicted values.
>
> 1 - Right-click the geostatistical layer in the ArcMap table of contents that was created using ordinary kriging and click Change output to Prediction Standard Error.

It would be nice if there was a theoretical explanation showing how the statistic is calculated (with examples).